# Whenever I refresh the page in meteor angular then `Meteor.user()` method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using `accounts-password@1.4.0` package in my Meteor angular project.

`Meteor.user()` method returns the current user details but when I refresh the page it returns `undefined`. 
So is there any way we can remove this error? Any help will be appreciated.

```
Meteor.autorun(function () {
  vm.loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
});
```

It's working fine but when I reload the page it returns `undefined`

```
Meteor.autorun(function () {
  vm.loggedInUser = Meteor.user();
  console.log("loggedInUser", vm.loggedInUser); // undefined
});
```

Comment: Your question is too broad. You should add more information and/or code, so we would be able to understand your issue.

Comment: I have improved my question with more information. It may help you

Comment: You meant `Tracker.autorun`, right?

Comment: I am working with meteor + angular

Answer (score 3):

When you refresh the page `Meteor.user()` will be undefined for a few cycles until its data has been retransmitted from server to client via websocket/ddp. It will eventually become defined and have the right data. Single-page applications like those built in Meteor don't usually require a page refresh but have to deal with the case of the user refreshing manually. A typical solution is to show a loading spinner until subscriptions and user data become ready.

Also it's `Tracker.autorun()` not `Meteor.autorun()`

Comment: It  retrieve the data from server when switch from one route to another.

Comment: How are you switching the route? Are you clicking on a link in your app? Or typing a new url into your browser? In the former case `Meteor.user()` should remain available whereas in the second case it's the same as doing a real page refresh.